# Updating options on dynamic selector with Vuejs2

Tags: design-patterns, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I have a problem updating the `options` array in a `select` tag in a VueJS component.

I have several rows and on `select` on each row. Each `select` will use the same `options` array. When one option is selected, that option should disappear from the others `select`.

I have try several ways to do that, but i'm not able to update the other options array (Using the `Vue.set(...)` function and all the caveats available).

The question in similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906643/vuejs-2-0-v-model-dynamic-target-inside-v-for) but:
 - selector's array has to be dynamic
 - Options are the same for each selector

That's why the solution on that question doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I should suggest you keep an array of usable options, and each time a value is selected, you `splice` the value from the usable options. When you `v-for` to create the list of options, you'll show only the ones that weren't selected yet.